# Position absolute changes image and object fit contain problem

Tags: html, css, css-position, css-grid

Image size is different with the presence and absence of `position:relative;` at `.container` and `position:absolute;` at `.container img`(child).

The code below works fine ( the image did not mess up the equally sized grid ). However, when both positions are removed, the grid doesn't follow the coded size ( in this case its `repeat(3,1fr)` and `repeat(4, 1fr)` )

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="issue.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
            <div class="container">
                <img src="./assets/pic/pic.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
*,
html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
}

.container {
    grid-row: 2/3;
    grid-column: 1/2;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.container img {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

Edit:
When I use `object-fit:contain;`, `overflow:hidden;` is a must in it.
My question is why is `overflow:hidden;` necessary to control the size of image? (HTML code is same as above, CSS code is below)

CSS:

```
*,
html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
}
.container {
    grid-row: 2/3;
    grid-column: 1/2;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container img {
    object-fit: contain;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

Note:
1.This is most likely not a browser bug as Mozilla and Chrome produce the same result.
2.The image can be any aspect ratio as long as it is larger than the container (for my case i used 512px × 768px)

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the actual size or ratio of "pic.jpg" I can't know for sure what the problem is. But since you said:

> When I use object-fit:contain  *[in the image]*;, overflow:hidden; is a must in it. My
> question is why is overflow:hidden; necessary to control the size of
> image? (HTML code is same as above, CSS code is below)

My bet is that the problem is the aspect ratio of the image. In this simplified example, the image has `object-fit: contain`, but the `img` still overflows its container:

```css
.container{
  width: 100px;
  height: 120px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

img{
  object-fit: contain;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  opacity: 0.8; /*just for visualization*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/180x140/FF8000/400202"/>
<div>
```

Here `height: 100%;` makes the image as tall as its container (that is: 120px), then `width: auto;` gives it *as much width as it is needed so the image keeps the same original aspect ratio*, that is:

(180px / 140px) X 120px == 154px

That is why you need to add `overflow: hidden;` to `containter`.

As an alternative, instead of modifying the containder's CSS, you can change `width: auto` by `width: 100%` in the image. This also has a drawback; if the image is too tall or large, part of the container wont be covered by the image. If you need to cover all the container, then you can also change `object-fit: contain;` by `object-fit: cover;`.

Comment: ```width:100%;```although did not cause it to overflow too much as compared to ```width:auto;```, however, it still did not respect the given size and extends the given grid size. (you could try to use a grid)
P.S : The image can be any aspect ratio as long as it is larger than the container (for my case i used 512px × 768px)

Comment: Although minmax can solve it and won't cause issue, but why can position absolute and relative be an alternative to it?